# Double EMA on Trading View using Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I can output a MA line using the code below, this will draw a 20 week EMA line which typically places the indicator line below the price since it is a lagging calculation.

```
//@version=5
indicator("weekly MA", overlay=true)
color c1 = color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 40)
l1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', ta.ema(close, 20))
plot(l1, color=c1, linewidth=1)
```

However, I would like to plot a Double EMA so that the red indicator line is above the price line like the example below, how can i code this using pine script?
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Do you need the formula to calculate double ema?

Comment: @BruceEcurb yes